# Как добавить окончание .html к URL-адресу ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Нужно добавить окончание `.html` для URL-адресов в ASP.NET MVC 5.
Чтобы было, например так:

```
http://example.com/category1/article1.html
```

Пытаюсь решить задачу так:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}.html",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
 );
```

Получаю ошибку 403.

Что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: `url: "{controller}/{action}.html"` что будет в таком случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выяснилось, что я всё сделал правильно. Только не до конца.

После того, как задан маршрут с суффиксом `.html`, нужно соответствующим образом  отредактировать web.config. Тогда всё заработает.

Ответ нашёл [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29272618/how-to-add-extension-html-in-url-asp-net-mvc-4). Хотя там рассматривается ASP.NET MVC 4, способ работает и для ASP.NET MVC 5.

```
<system.webServer>
    ...
    <handlers>
      <add name="HtmlFileHandler" path="*.html" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    ...
  </system.webServer>
```

**Важное замечание**

Помимо основного маршрута (с `.html` в конце) необходимо определить дополнительный с пустым шаблоном `url`, как это показано ниже.

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

 routes.MapRoute(
     name: "html",
     url: "{controller}/{action}.html",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Если этого не сделать, главная страница сайта будет не доступна по имени домена. Тогда вместо:

```
http://example.com/
```

придётся явно указывать соответствующие главной странице контроллер и действие

```
http://example.com/Home/Index.html
```

Либо делать редирект.

Comment: Если проблема решена, отметье ответ как ответ галкой.

Comment: @tym32167, отметить не вопрос. Только система не позволяет поставить галочку у собственного ответа на свой вопрос сразу. Потому, увы, придётся ещё немного подождать.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.